# Match of carriage return, line feed and multiple space in javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying replace carriage return (\r) and newline (\n) and more than one spaces ('  ' ) with single space.

I used \W+ which helped to achieve this but, it's replacing special characters also with space. I want to change this only replace above characters.

Please help me with proper regular expression with replace method in javascript.

Comment: My sample data can be like this. A   B C  D\rE\r\n F

Comment: Is it `\r` AND `\n` AND more than one space, or `\r` OR `\n` OR more than one space, because your question asks for the first but anubhava has provided the regex for the second.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will work: `/\n|\s{2,}/g`

```
var res = str.replace(/\n|\s{2,}/g, " ");
```

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/pQ8zU1/1

Comment: selecteditem = selecteditem.replace(/\r|\n|\s{2,}/, ' ');  Only the first match is working after that it's not working.But in the tool it's working fine.

Comment: @user970503 You need to enable the `global` flag by adding a `g` after the ending `/`.

Comment: yes it's my miss. It worked fantastically after appending g. Thanks for helping me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 7):

```
\s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
```

You should use `\s{2,}` for this.It is made for this task.

Answer (score 0):

This simple one should suit your needs: `/[\r\n ]{2,}/g`. Replace by a space.